# Implementing cross domain single sign on (OAuth or impelementing my own)

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on

I need to implement a single sign on solution for a couple of websites in my company. I want to have the minimum interaction with the user during this process. It should look like its the same application.

I have studied OAuth , stack Exchange and youtube If I understand correctly OAuth the user has allways to give permission to the app right?.

Do you think I could use OAuth or should I implement a similar mechanism like youtube or stack exchange myself? In the begining I was more inclined to that idea but I dont want to reeinvent the wheel. Also I dont have many time to impelement this.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you should not "reinvent the wheel".

You *can* use **oAuth**, even though it is not defined as SSO solution (and you wrote that you are interested in SSO solution - are you sure about the meaning of SSO?).

Have a look at **SAML**, which *IS* defined as Single Sign On, etc. But you have to be more precise about your requirements - do you want to implement the identity provider by yourself, or can you use Google Accounts, for example?

Comment: I wnat to implement my own identity provider. Lets say I have domainA.com and domainB.com. The user should not note any difference when switching domains. In my research I found many references to SAML, but I didnt understand how it works. I will take a deeper look at it.